# Submitting a file to GitHub without my personal details

Tags: git

There is a small script which I would like to submit to GitHub. The script requires username and password and contains the two following lines:

```
$username = "[enter your username here]"
$password = "[enter your password here]"
```

Since I use same the script on my computer, I write my own username and password in the file:

```
$username = "[my-username]"
$password = "[my-password]"
```

The problem is, when I insert my details into the file, git detects that the file has changed and suggests to submit the changes, which of course I don't want.

I don't want to keep two separate versions of the file, one for me and one for GitHub, because this requires to make any correction and bug-fix in two locations.

I also don't want to use a separate configuration file and put it in .gitignore, because this will make the installation of my script more cumbersome - anyone downloading my script will have to create this configuration file on his computer.

What I want is to tell git that a *single* change (the change in which I insert my username and password into the file) should not be commited, while changes made afterwards should be commited as usual. Is this possible with git?

Comment: Why not simply use one branch (e.g. `master`) for the publishable version and another (e.g. `perso`) for your own?

Comment: Put the variables in another file (like `config.lang`), exclude that from `.gitignore`, and add a `config.example.lang` so others know how to use it, then include `config.lang` in your code.

Comment: @Jubobs That would also push to GitHub if he pushed all branches, and wouldn't make much sense, as he would have to maintain two copies of the same code.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx If he follows my approach, the OP should only push the `master` branch to GitHub and keep the other local; besides, he could very straightforwardly merge whatever changes occur on `master` into the other branch, in order to keep the latter up to date; no hassle at all.

Comment: @Jubobs Then, I'm not really sure how else you could solve it. You could use environment variables, but depending on how the script works that could be worse.

Comment: Aside from just editing it every single time.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx Under the assumption that the script file contains both lines before and after the two lines of interest here, you could use two branches as described above, with little risk of merge conflicts.

Comment: Can you use the small configuration file (listed in `.gitignore`) and have the application create it automatically the first time it's run? Also, you should think about the security implications of storing a password in clear text; at the very least, the file should be made readable only by the owner when it's created. (permissions `600` if you're on a UNIX-like system).